# vscode - is there an option to toggle on only one break point?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

All my break points are toggled off, I would like to turn on only 1 break point.
Is there such option?

The only option I could find so far is to uncheck all break points, but the needed one, one by one.

Comment: No, I don't believe there is such an option.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the debugger to break when a program starts can require tooling and/or a configuration, both of which are going to be platform dependent. Because V.S. Code has native support for **JavaScript** & the JS RTE, **Node.js**, I assume you are talking about the JS/Node.js debuggers.

##### The process below will vary from language to language, but this will give you an idea of how to use a flag for a debugger, and attach the debugger to your projects running script.

---

You will need to configure the debugger to attach to node processes, we will specifically setup or debugger so it only attaches when we use the **`--inspect`** flag, and we will actually be using a special inspect flag (more on flags below)

##### Add the Following Setting, with the same value as below, to Your `"settings.json"` File

---

```
    // "./.vscode/settings.json" (can be either user, or workspace, settings.json file.


    {
        "debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "onlyWithFlag"
    }
```

Then your going to use the `--inspect-brk` flag with the `node` CLI command to run your file, like you see below. (Its important to note that setting a flag using `--inspect-brk` is a **[Node.js Feature](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/), and is not a V.S. Code Feature**.)

- ###### *[Checkout this link to read about the --inspect-brk flag](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)*

```
~\$ echo "In the consoles CmdL run your code with the following flag"
~\$ node --inspect-brk index.js
```

After running your script with the command above, your debugger should automatically open, and it should break instantly.

If the debugger doesn't open automatically then its because you either didn't configured the debugger in correct way, or you didn't enter the `--inspect-brk` flag correctly.

If you have trouble, [go to this site to read about configuring how to attach the debugger.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

Comment: JAY-DEV, thank you for the detailed answer.
I assumed that the breakpoint panel is the same for all languages, my bad. 
actually I'm debugging in Python. 
never the less you gave me a direction to look into, thanks!

Comment: @Gil VSCode uses extensions to implement individual debuggers, therefore, each language needs its own debugging extension in V.S. Code. Debuggers are as far from a one-size fits all paradigm as one can get. One thing I didn't like about python, was its debugger, I use to had the JS debugger too, but now the JavaScript debugger w/ chrome dev tools feels like I am debugging a traditional OOP language so I started writing JS, but there was a fork in the road 6 years ago when I choose between learning the two languages.

Comment: @Gil anyhow, I believe you can use `debugpy.breakpoint()` to hardcore a break point anywhere in your code. You can checkout this link, it has some useful info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_invoking-a-breakpoint-in-code then of course there is the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find is by disabling all breakpoints in VSCode, and adding a new breakpoint in the Debug Console by "b  line_number"